# What is the default user for logging into cache terminal

Tags: intersystems-cache

I have installed cache locally, and when trying to log in with the terminal, I get a USER> prompt. I insert the default users listed in the management portal - Admin, _SYSTEM etc. and I get a  error.

What user and password should I use to log into the local server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see USER> prompt, it means you already logged, usually as UnknownUser. Which error you get? 
If your installation with minimal security level, then password will be SYS by default, with usernames _SYSTEM, Admin.